# Rearranging linear system containing a symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-calculus, tensors, symmetric-matrices

I'm trying to rearrange the following equation to get only Q on the LHS:

$$
A = -Q + t(Q M + M^T Q - kQ)
$$

Q is a symmetric matrix. A is a known symmetric matrix, M is an unknown non-symmetric matrix. t, k are known constants.

This seemed straightforward to me at first given all terms share a common Q, but non-commutativity of the terms is tripping me up. I could inject identity matrices and vectorize both sides, but I'd rather keep this in matrix form if possible.

Comment: What is your $M$ here?

Comment: Ah apologies - M is also a known (non-symmetric) matrix here. Also noted that A is symmetric. Editing accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

We can write
$$
\begin{align}
A &= -Q + t (QM + M^T Q - k Q) \\
&= - Q + tQM + tM^T Q - ktQ \\
&= - Q + \left( t M^T Q \right)^T +  \left( tM^T Q \right) - ktQ \\
&= -(1 +kt)Q + \left( t M^T Q \right)^T +  \left( tM^T Q \right),
\end{align}
$$
which clearly is a symmetric matrix.

I don't think we can do much more than this to factor out $Q$.